# Invalid cookie on submitting a form with Codeception

Tags: php, cookies, paypal, codeception, guzzle

I'm trying to test my project with Codeception (acceptance tests). Everything was going fine until I had to submit a form with Paypal button.
When debugging it shows

```
I submit form "form:nth-child(3)",
[Uri] https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
[Method] POST
[Parameters] {"cmd":"_s-xclick","hosted_button_id":"BUTTONID"}
ERROR
```

And then goes

```
[RuntimeException] Invalid cookie: The cookie value must not be empty
```

I DO NOT set any cookies during the test. And have no clue why is it firing this error up.

Here's my acceptance.suite.yml

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://test.mysite.com
        - \Helper\Acceptance
```

Here's my SubscriptionCest.php:

```
<?php
use \AcceptanceTester;

class SubscriptionCest
{
    public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
    }

    public function _after(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
    }

    // Main function
    public function run(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->am("New user");
        $I->wantTo("purchase a membership");
        $I->amOnPage("/subscription");

        $I->submitForm("form:nth-child(3)", []);
    }
}
```

And here's the HTML of that paypal form:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="BUTTONID">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Why does this error happen and how to resolve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out it was a bug, which is now fixed. Version 2.1 should have it working like a charm. For more information please check out https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2234